# Identify runs in R, allowing for gaps

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

I have already used the help boards on here to identify runs in R. For example:

```
temp.data = rle(c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA))
output = temp.data$lengths[temp.data$value==1]
```

Here, 'output' returns the following:

```
NA NA  1 NA NA  1 NA  3 NA NA NA
```

This works, telling me that there were runs of 1, 1, and 3. However, in addition to what I've done above, I would also like to identify runs with some level of "forgiveness". For example, if 1 represents an event occurring, and NA indicates that the event did not occur, I want to allow gaps of one. Thus, I would like my output to read:

```
NA NA 1 NA NA 5 NA NA NA
```

Alternatively, it could simply return that there were runs of 1 and 5. I am trying to do this across a data frame with several columns and hundreds of rows, with each cell being a list of 1's and NA's, thus I would like to automate the process. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to replace leading and trailing single `NA`s with 1 as well? Like in `x1 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA)`.

Comment: No, but I realized afterward I hadn't clarified on this. Your original answer works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create run lengths of `NA`, replace runs of `NA` of length 1 with `FALSE`. Then replace values of `x` indexed by `!inverse.rle(r)`:

```
r <- rle(is.na(x))
r$values[r$values][r$lengths[r$values] == 1] <- FALSE
x[!inverse.rle(r)] <- 1
x
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA
```

---

If you don't mind using non-`base`, `zoo::na.approx` and its `maxgap` argument is a convenient wrapper:

```
na.approx(x, maxgap = 1, na.rm = FALSE)
# [1] NA NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA
```

`na.approx` can also be fed with a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA),
                x2 = c(1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1))

na.approx(d, maxgap = 1, na.rm = FALSE)
#      x1 x2
# [1,] NA  1
# [2,]  1  1
# [3,]  1  1
# [4,]  1 NA
# [5,]  1 NA
# [6,] NA  1
```

---

If your data set is large, you may work with `data.table` in a 'long' format:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

# convert to long format
d2 <- melt(d, measure.var = names(d))

# for each variable and run, add group number and group length
d2[ , `:=`(g = .GRP, n = .N), by = .(variable, rleid(value))]

# for each variable, replace runs of `NA` of length 1 with 1
# leave leading and trailing NA (exclude first and last group)
d2[ , value := replace(value, is.na(value) & n == 1 &
                         g != min(g) & g != max(g), 1),
    by = .(variable)][ 
      , `:=`(g = NULL, n = NULL)] # clean-up
d2
#     variable value
#  1:       x1    NA
#  2:       x1     1
#  3:       x1     1
#  4:       x1     1
#  5:       x1     1
#  6:       x1    NA
#  7:       x2     1
#  8:       x2     1
#  9:       x2     1
# 10:       x2    NA
# 11:       x2    NA
# 12:       x2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way in base R. The basic idea is to first replace `NA` by `0` (so that the output of `rle` is more informative), then tweak this output and reconstruct it so that *isolated* 0s have been replaced by 1's. Finally, `rle()` of the result works as you want:

```
> x <- c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA)
> x[is.na(x)] <- 0
> temp.data = rle(x)
> temp.data$values[temp.data$values == 0 & temp.data$lengths == 1] <- 1
> y <- inverse.rle(temp.data)
> rle(y)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 2 5 3
  values : num [1:5] 0 1 0 1 0
```